# find the $ \sum_{1}^n f_k?$ and find the $ \sum_{1}^{\infty} f_k?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\{f_n\}$ be  a sequence  of real   nonnegative  functions  on $\mathbb{R}$

Given  $f_n(x)=\begin{cases}  1  \ \text{if x}  \in [\frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n}] \\ 0  \ \text{if  x} \notin [\frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n}] \end{cases}$

My question: find the  $ \sum_{1}^n f_k ?$   and find the  $ \sum_{1}^{\infty} f_k?$

My attempt : Given $f_n(x)=\begin{cases}  1  \ \text{if x}  \in [\frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n}] \\ 0  \ \text{if  x} \notin [\frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n}] \end{cases}$

$f_1 + f_2 +....+f_n=\sum f_k=\begin{cases}  n  \ \text{if  x}  \in [\frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n}] \\ 0  \ \text{if  x} \notin [\frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n}] \end{cases}$

Is it  true ?

For  $ \sum_{1}^{\infty} f_k$

$f_1 + f_2 +....+f_n+....=\sum f_k=\begin{cases} \infty  \ \text{if x}  \in [\frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n}] \\ 0  \ \text{if  x} \notin [\frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n}] \end{cases}$

Is  it  true ?

Comment: You should check the intervals when you sum, this doesn't seem correct at all.

Comment: @Maxence1402 I think interval will remain constant

Comment: @Koro  yes $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: It baffles me how one seems to have a lot of experience in maths but struggles to compute this simple sum of functions. Koro's answer should be really helpful.

Comment: BTw    I haven't had a lot of experiences, @Maxence1402 **Sometimes the easiest thing are the most difficult to come up with**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let's take one example: suppose that we fix $x=\frac \pi 4$ ($\lt 0.79$), then clearly $\frac 1{1+1}\lt x\lt \frac 11$ and hence $x\notin [\frac 1{n+1},\frac 1n]$ for any $n\gt 1$ so $f_1(x)=1$ and $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n\gt 1$.

Let $x\ne 1/i$ for any $i\in \mathbb N$, then for any $1\gt x\gt 0$, we have an $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac 1{n+1}\lt x \lt \frac 1n$

So $f_1(x)+f_2(x)+\dots+f_n(x)=0+0+\dots+1=1$

But if $x=\frac 1i$ for some $i\in \mathbb N$ then note that there will be two closed intervals (of the form $[\frac 1{m+1}, \frac 1m]$) sharing $x$ so....?

Comment: that  means  $\sum{f_n} $ will be $\{0,1,2\}$  @ Koro Am i right ?

Comment: yes, depending on values of $x$. I have added one example. You may have a look at that @jasmine