# why $\{f<1\} =(-\infty,0]?$ why not $\{f<1\} =(0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

MIT  source :  Question $2$c [link](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.125/HW6.pdf) and Solution $2$c link [pdf](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.125/Solutions/PS6_2.pdf)

Question :let $\{f_n\}$ be  sequence  of real value function ,nonnegative  function on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove or disprove  each of the  following statement

> If each  $f_n$ is upper semicontnious ,then  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ is uppers semicontnious

I have some confusion in this image  [image]

**My  confusion** :  Im not getting  why $\{f<1\} =(-\infty,0]?$ why not $\{f<1\} =(0,\infty)$?

**My thinking** : It is given  that  $f(x)=\sum_{n} f_n(x)$  where  $f_n(x)=\begin{cases}  1  \ \text{if x}  \in [\frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n}] \\ 0  \ \text{if  x} \notin [\frac{1}{n+1} ,\frac{1}{n}] \end{cases}$

This implies   $f(x)  \in \{0,1,2\} $ for all  $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Suppose    $x =\frac{1}{\pi} \neq 1/k$  for  any $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Then $f_1(x)=1$ and $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n\gt 1$.

This implies  $\{f<1\} =(0,1)$

Comment: What's the underlying domain? Because $f<1$ would just be the complement of the union of the intervals $[1/(n+1),1/n]$ which assuming $n$ starts at $1$ will be the complement of $(0,1]$, whatever that is in the domain.

Comment: @Ian $\{f_n\}$   is  sequence  of real nonnegative function on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes, you are right!@Ian  I think something is wrong in a given solution. It contained a typo.

Comment: you  are right @OliverDiaz I think there's a typo  in a given solution

Comment: @jasmine How do you find that $f(x) = 0 $ for all $x \in \{ \frac{1}{n} \}$? Is not $f(1) = 1$, $f(1/2) = 2$ and so on?

Comment: @user2005142 see my  [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222830/find-the-sum-1n-f-k-and-find-the-sum-1-infty-f-k?rq=1)

Comment: @jasmine but for instance, $\frac{1}{2} \in [\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]$ only for $n = 1, 2$. So $\sum_{n = 1}^{N} f_n(\frac{1}{2}) = 2$ for all $N \geq 2$, since  $f_n(\frac{1}{2}) = \begin{cases}1,& n \in \{1, 2\} \\ 0 & \text{else} \\\end{cases}$

Comment: yes you  are right @user2005142    same logic I've often said in my question

Comment: @user2005142 I have assume  $x \neq \frac{1}{k}$

Comment: @user2005142 i edited

Comment: @jasmine: I guess the goal of the exercise what to show that infinite the supremum of upper semicontinuous functions is not necessarily upper semicontinuous. Considering the $f_n$'s in your posting as defines over all the real line, $\max_{1\leq k\leq n}f_k(x)=\mathbb{1}_{[\tfrac{1}{n+1},1]}(x)$ which is upper semicontinuous (being the indicator function if a closed interval). However $f(x)=\sup_nf_n(x)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,1]}$ is not upper semicontinuous as $\{f<1\}=(-\infty,0]\cup(1,\infty)$ which is not open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I have added a reference

Comment: @jasmine: I have no issue with references. After all this is a textbook problem and not a deep theorem in a paper by Andrei Kolmogorov.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x>0$ (and $x \le 1$) then for some $n$, $x$ will be in $[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac1n]$ for some $n$ and then $f_n(x) =1$ there and so $f(x) \ge 1$ for those $x$. $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$ so $f(0) =0 < 1$ and so on the domain $(-\infty, 1]$ we have $\{x\mid f(x) < 1\} = (-\infty, 0]$ as claimed. But in the example I don't see an explicit domain for the $f_n$, but if $x>1$ would have been allowed all $f_n(x)=0$ for $x$ there as well and we'd add $(1, +\infty)$ to the inverse image.